# How to create the multi Set for CPLEX OPL

Tags: opl

I want create the multi of paths (e.g. three paths) that store the link<i,j>, but get the error. Ask everyone what can I modify?

```
   tuple path{
     {int} p;
   }
   {path} ps={1,2,3};
```

I think that sample way is create the three sets.

```
{int} p1;
{int} p2;
{int} p3;
```

Comment: Add to the question the exact text of the error

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple path{
     {int} p;
   }
{path} ps={<{1}>,<{2}>,<{3}>};

execute
{
  writeln(ps);
}
```

works fine

Comment: Thx. and are these empty sets ? Because I hope sets are dvar (using store the selected link<i,j>).

Comment: You could use that set on index a dvar array : dvar int x[ps];

Comment: Hey, and then how to transfor ps set to array? I need give the number [1..3] that can correspond to anyone set in ps set .

Comment: {int} pathsarray[i in 1..card(ps)]=item(ps,i-1).p;